# Convergent infinite sum

Tags: calculus

For which p the sum is convergent?

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^p}\ln\frac{n-1}{n+1}
$$
Clearly I have no idea how to solve problems of this type,tipsI think will help me

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln \frac{n-1}{n+1} = \ln \left(1 - \frac 2{n+1}\right) \sim - \frac 2{n+1} \sim -\frac 2n$$

while $$\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt n \sim 2\sqrt n$$

So the $n$-th term of the sequence is asymptotic to

$$-\frac 1 {2^p n^{p/2}} \cdot \frac 2{n} = -\frac{2^{1-p}}{n^{p/2+1}}$$

Now it should be easy! :-)